# select all lines from 2 tables with same id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, union

I have two tables in my database that looks like that :

```
TABLE1 
user_id 
value1
value2

TABLE2 
user_id
value3
value4
```

I would like to make a query to get all the lines from TABLE1 and TABLE2 that have an user_id = 1.

I have done :

```
SELECT TABLE1.user_id,TABLE1,value1, TABLE1.value2, TABLE2.value3, TABLE2.value4
 FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.user_id = TABLE2.user_id 
WHERE TABLE.user_id = 1
```

But I get all the values in one row, I'd like to get all the different row from those 2 tables where the user_id = 1..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do a UNION ALL instead of the join.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select 't1' which, user_id, value1, value2 from table1 where user_id = 1
union all
select 't2', user_id, value3, value4 from table2 where user_id = 1
```

You did not specify exactly the resultset that you want to get. This gives you a dataset made of 4 columns, where the first column contains the name of the table where the user was found. Columns 3 and 4 contain either `value1` and `value2` (if the row comes from `table1`), or `value3` and `value4` (if the row comes from `table2`).

This can only work if `value1` and `value3` (resp. `value2` and `value4`) have the same datatype (and length). If that's not the case, then you would better have separate columns in the resultset:

```
select 't1' which, user_id, value1, value2, null value3, null valu4
from table1 where user_id = 1
union all
select 't2', user_id, null, null, value3, value4 
from table2 
where user_id = 1
```